# Reading CSV data as headers and value pairs

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file and take the headers as key and the body as the value pairs. 
Here is my Python file:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import requests

import csv
import sys
data = {}

def readCsv(csvFile, column):
    with open(csvFile, "rb") as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        headers = next(reader)[1:]
        for row in reader:
            data[row[column]] = {key: value for key, value in zip(headers, row[1:])}

def readCalllogs():
    for loanNumber in data:
        logDetail = data[loanNumber]
        print logDetail
        resp = requests.post('http://localhost:3500/api/v1/call_logs', json=logDetail)
        if resp.status_code != 201:
                print resp.status_code
        else:
            print logDetail

def writeYAMLFile():
    for loan in loans:
        print loan["assignedTo"]


def loadCalllogsFromCsv():
    readCsv("calllogs.csv", 0)
    readCalllogs()

def main():
    loadCalllogsFromCsv()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I am getting an Index error:

> File "./load_calllogs.py", line 16, in readCsv
>       data[row[column]] = {key: value for key, value in zip(headers, row[1:])}
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Here is my CSV file:

```
loanNumber,date,contactStatus,contactRelation,contactName,response,tenantId,actionDate,action,assignedTo,remarks,caller
1,,CONNECTED,SELF,NAME1,RESPONSE1,,,FIELD_PTP,ASSIGN1,REMARK1,CALLER1
2,,WRONG_NUMBER,SELF,NAME2,RESPONSE2,,,MEET_GUARANTOR,ASSIGN2,REMARK2,CALLER2
3,,CONNECTED,WIFE,NAME3,RESPONSE3,,,FIELD_PTP,ASSIGN3,REMARK3,CALLER3
4,,NO_RESPONSE,HUSBAND,NAME4,RESPONSE4,,,MEET_GUARANTOR,ASSIGN4,REMARK4,CALLER4
5,,CONNECTED,SON,NAME5,RESPONSE5,,,VISIT_CUSTOMER,ASSIGN5,REMARK5,CALLER5
6,,CONNECTED,SON,NAME6,RESPONSE6,,,VISIT_CUSTOMER,ASSIGN6,REMARK6,CALLER6
```

Comment: Just use `csv.DictReader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this code.

```
file = "your_file.csv"

my_list = []

with open(file, mode='r') as input_file:
    rows = []
    for row in input_file:
        rows.append(row.rstrip('\n').split(","))
    keys = rows[0]
    for values in rows[1:]:
        my_list.append(dict(zip(keys, values)))
```

Here is the output (a list containing dicts):

> [{'actionDate': '', 'caller': 'CALLER1', 'contactStatus': 'CONNECTED', 'contactName': 'NAME1', 'tenantId': '', 'loanNumber': '1', 'action': 'FIELD_PTP', 'contactRelation': 'SELF', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN1', 'remarks': 'REMARK1', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE1'}, {'actionDate': '', 'caller': 'CALLER2', 'contactStatus': 'WRONG_NUMBER', 'contactName': 'NAME2', 'tenantId': '', 'loanNumber': '2', 'action': 'MEET_GUARANTOR', 'contactRelation': 'SELF', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN2', 'remarks': 'REMARK2', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE2'}, {'actionDate': '', 'caller': 'CALLER3', 'contactStatus': 'CONNECTED', 'contactName': 'NAME3', 'tenantId': '', 'loanNumber': '3', 'action': 'FIELD_PTP', 'contactRelation': 'WIFE', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN3', 'remarks': 'REMARK3', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE3'}, {'actionDate': '', 'caller': 'CALLER4', 'contactStatus': 'NO_RESPONSE', 'contactName': 'NAME4', 'tenantId': '', 'loanNumber': '4', 'action': 'MEET_GUARANTOR', 'contactRelation': 'HUSBAND', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN4', 'remarks': 'REMARK4', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE4'}, {'actionDate': '', 'caller': 'CALLER5', 'contactStatus': 'CONNECTED', 'contactName': 'NAME5', 'tenantId': '', 'loanNumber': '5', 'action': 'VISIT_CUSTOMER', 'contactRelation': 'SON', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN5', 'remarks': 'REMARK5', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE5'}, {'actionDate': '', 'caller': 'CALLER6', 'contactStatus': 'CONNECTED', 'contactName': 'NAME6', 'tenantId': '', 'loanNumber': '6', 'action': 'VISIT_CUSTOMER', 'contactRelation': 'SON', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN6', 'remarks': 'REMARK6', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE6'}]

Comment: thanks..... actually i am trying to learn python. So, I was thinking not to use any sort of automation. Your answer helped me.

Answer (score 3):

A [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) would help you. It automatically reads the header in and then converts each following row into a dictionary based on that row. Columns are then accessed by their name, rather than their position:

```
import csv

data = {}

def readCsv(csvFile, column):
    with open(csvFile, "rb") as infile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)

        for row in reader:
            data[row[column]] = row

readCsv("calllogs.csv", 'loanNumber')
print data
```

This would give you:

```
{'1': {'actionDate': '', 'loanNumber': '1', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN1', 'caller': 'CALLER1', 'tenantId': '', 'action': 'FIELD_PTP', 'remarks': 'REMARK1', 'contactName': 'NAME1', 'contactRelation': 'SELF', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE1', 'contactStatus': 'CONNECTED'}, '3': {'actionDate': '', 'loanNumber': '3', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN3', 'caller': 'CALLER3', 'tenantId': '', 'action': 'FIELD_PTP', 'remarks': 'REMARK3', 'contactName': 'NAME3', 'contactRelation': 'WIFE', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE3', 'contactStatus': 'CONNECTED'}, '2': {'actionDate': '', 'loanNumber': '2', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN2', 'caller': 'CALLER2', 'tenantId': '', 'action': 'MEET_GUARANTOR', 'remarks': 'REMARK2', 'contactName': 'NAME2', 'contactRelation': 'SELF', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE2', 'contactStatus': 'WRONG_NUMBER'}, '5': {'actionDate': '', 'loanNumber': '5', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN5', 'caller': 'CALLER5', 'tenantId': '', 'action': 'VISIT_CUSTOMER', 'remarks': 'REMARK5', 'contactName': 'NAME5', 'contactRelation': 'SON', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE5', 'contactStatus': 'CONNECTED'}, '4': {'actionDate': '', 'loanNumber': '4', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN4', 'caller': 'CALLER4', 'tenantId': '', 'action': 'MEET_GUARANTOR', 'remarks': 'REMARK4', 'contactName': 'NAME4', 'contactRelation': 'HUSBAND', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE4', 'contactStatus': 'NO_RESPONSE'}, '6': {'actionDate': '', 'loanNumber': '6', 'assignedTo': 'ASSIGN6', 'caller': 'CALLER6', 'tenantId': '', 'action': 'VISIT_CUSTOMER', 'remarks': 'REMARK6', 'contactName': 'NAME6', 'contactRelation': 'SON', 'date': '', 'response': 'RESPONSE6', 'contactStatus': 'CONNECTED'}}
```

You will note that the `loadNumber` field is used as the key which is also left in the dictionary itself.

Comment: Actually i was trying to face the problem without any automation(DictReader) thanks anyway ..... Thanks anyway

Comment: No problem. Just to warn you though, if you use the `split()` approach it will fail if the CSV happens to have any additional escaping, e.g. a remark field contains a comma and has had quotes added to it. The Python library takes care of all of that automatically.